# Return const char* from shared_ptr<std::string> not displaying characters in std::out

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

const char* read_from_stdin(void) {
    std::shared_ptr<std::string> m_buffer(new std::string);
    std::getline(std::cin, *m_buffer);
    if (!std::cin.good())
        return nullptr;

    while (!m_buffer->empty() && (m_buffer->back() == '\r') || (m_buffer->back() == '\n')) {
        m_buffer->pop_back();
    }

    return reinterpret_cast<const char*>(m_buffer->c_str());
}

int main()
{
   std::cout << "You entered: " << read_from_stdin() << "\n";
}
```

**It returns the following:**

[image]

I am on Windows 11 with Microsoft Visual Studio running this in debug mode, and no I haven't checked for UTF-8.

**EDIT:** I can observe the characters inside the `[ptr]` inside the `shared_ptr<T>()` object.

Comment: Your code destroys the `string` stored in the unnecessary `shared_ptr` upon exiting the function. Then you access freed data from the main. That's a UB plain and simple. Also the code would try to print C-string at `nullptr` depending on input - this is also a bug.

Comment: Why don't you simply return a `std::string` from `read_from_stdin` ?

Comment: **ALX23z** & **wohlstad**, you are both correct mates. I sorted it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of `std::shared_ptr` is to keep an object alive as long as there are `std::shared_ptr` instances actively referring to it. Once there are no more references to it, the object is destroyed.

If you extract a raw pointer from a `std::string` object in a `std::shared_ptr` (as with `m_buffer->c_str()`), then you still need to make sure that the pointer value does not live longer than the `std::string` instance from which you have obtained it. The raw pointer does not extend lifetime.

Your (only) `std::shared_ptr` instance that refers to the `std::string` object lives only until the end of the function scope, but the raw pointer value lives longer than that because you return it from the function. So the pointer can't be used by the function caller, as it points to memory that is freed when the `std::string` is destroyed when the function exits.

So, you can't return a `char*` from your function. You need to return the whole `std::shared_ptr`. Otherwise, you can't extend the lifetime of the object beyond the function call.

However, from what you are showing, there is no reason to use `std::shared_ptr` at all. You can simply use and return a `std::string` variable.

---

Also the `reinterpret_cast` does nothing. `std::string::c_str()` already returns a `const char*`. `reinterpret_cast` is only useful in very specific situations, and in almost all other situations will only cause undefined behavior eventually. Don't use it carelessly.

---

Also, `(!m_buffer->empty() && (m_buffer->back() == '\r') || (m_buffer->back() == '\n')` won't do what you think it will. `&&` has higher operator precedence than `||`. So, if `m_buffer` is empty, then it will still call `m_buffer->back()` to test `(m_buffer->back() == '\n')`, causing undefined behavior. Always add parentheses when you mix `&&`/`||` boolean expressions to avoid such mistakes.